# Mapping simple related objects with Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

i have two related objects, User & Country...i want to Merge both **UserName** and **CountryName** in a single DTOobject

```
public class User
{   
    public long Id { get; set; }    
    public string UserName { get; set; }    
    public long IdCountry { get; set; } 

    public virtual Country CountryObj { get; set; } 
}
```

Every **User** in the database has a **Country**

```
public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.User = new List<User>();
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

I want to merge both **UserName** and **CountryName** in my DTO

```
public class DTOUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }        
}
```

this is my mapping, **i think something is wrong in here**

```
public AutoMapperProfiles()
{
    CreateMap<User, DTOUser>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x=> x.CountryObj.CountryName));
}
```

When i execute my application for some reason the country **returns null**

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "UserName ",
        "CountryName ": null,           
    }
]
```

I can't solve this problem

**EDIT**

HERE IS MY OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(x => x.CountryObj)
                .WithMany(x => x.User)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: So what is the code you execute the mapper?It works well in my project.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework to load your data? If so are you sure you have correctly included the `User.CountryObj` property when loading the user?

Comment: I included my OnModelCreating in the post, maybe that is my problem

Comment: You need share how do you use the IMapper to map the dtos.